# PING a módem GPRS

Tags: socket, tcpip

tengo poco conocimiento en redes y tengo una pregunta.
Estoy tratando de hacer PING a un módem GPRS desde un pc pero no lo consigo.
Tengo entendido que el problema es debido a algo sobre las APN, algo así que ambos equipos deben estar en la misma APN. Pero no me queda claro porqué.

Alguien pudiera aclararme esta duda? gracias de ante mano.

Comment: Un módem GPRS no tiene dirección IP, funciona a nivel de enlace/físico. ¿Se trata de un módem GPRS o de un router con módem GPRS?

Comment: si, es un módem router GPRS para aplicaciones M2M. Ejemplo (Enfora GSM 1318)

Comment: Entonces es un módem normal, controlado por [comandos AT (Hayes)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunto_de_comandos_Hayes#AT). Funciona a nivel de enlace estableciendo conexión con el otro extremo mediante [PPP](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-Point_Protocol). El dispositivo no tiene dirección IP, el ordenador conectado al módem negocia la dirección IP con el otro extremo y la IP se asignará a dicho ordenador, no al módem.

Comment: Ok entiendo eso, pero porque no puedo hacer un PING al otro ordenador si no estoy conectado a internet a traves de la misma APN?

Comment: Ahh, eso ya es diferente. Entonces lo que quieres es hacer PING al ordenador que está conectado al módem. ¿No? ¿Qué sistema operativo tiene dicho ordenador?

Comment: Ambos windows, la pregunta en cuestión es, si tengo un ordenador conectado a internet a través de una red GPRS y el otro a través de una WAN, porqué no puedo hacer un PING? pero en cambio si puedo si tengo ambos ordenadores conectados a internet a través de GPRS con el mismo operador movil y la misma APN.

Comment: ¿Has probado a hacer un `traceroute` (`tracert` en Windows) entre ambas máquinas para ver en qué salto se pierde el tráfico? Es posible que el operador que te ofrece la conectividad GPRS esté filtrando el tráfico hacia tu máquina. ¿El problema ocurre en ambos sentidos o sólo en uno? (es decir, ¿si pruebas a hacer ping del otro equipo al primero tampoco funciona?)

Comment: En realidad el otro ordenador es el mismo módem, el cual tiene acceso a internet por medio de su sim card. Al momento de adquirirse el plan de datos, la sim card viene con una ip definida (verticales.movistar.com.co) y en el momento en que el módem se engancha a la red, yo solo puedo hacerle un ping desde un ordenador que esté enganchado a la red por medio de un celular del mismo operador y que este operando con la misma apn

Comment: lo que quiero saber es porque sucede esto?, porque no puedo hacer ping si el ordenador está enganchado a la rede desde una apn distinta o desde el internet de la casa

Comment: La asociación entre tu SIM y la IP es similar a como se hace con una IP estática asignada en DHCP. No está "escrita" en la SIM, si no que al negociar la IP con el otro extremo, se la tiene reservada para su uso exclusivo, pero no puedes hacerle ping a esa IP hasta que un equipo, haciendo uso de ese módem, negocia la IP y mantiene el enlace abierto (recuerda que la conexión PPP trabaja a nivel de enlace). ¿Podrías poner un esquema de cómo funciona y cómo no funciona en tu pregunta?

Comment: Voy a tratar de ponerte en contexto, tengo un módem enfora gsm 1318 el cual tiene una sim card movistar que tiene una ip definida, una apn (verticales.movistar.com.co), un usuario y una contraseña. El modem se utiliza para controlar un equipo al cual se conecta por puerto serial rs232 y se accesa a él por medio de una aplicación tcp cliente servidor. pero la idea es comprobar el estado de la conexión haciendo un ping al módem. Yo puedo lograr esto SOLO si el pc donde hago la petición, está conectado a internet por medio de un celular con sim card movistar y con la misma APN configurada

Comment: Vale, eso mismo deberías agregarlo en tu pregunta pulsando el enlace ["editar"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/167758/edit) que hay bajo ella. ¿Has podido probar lo del `tracert`? ¿Has podido probar lo de hacer ping en ambos sentidos?

Comment: Voy a hacer lo del tracert para ver hasta donde llega la petición, pero en todo caso ya conseguí la respuesta a través del mismo operador. el problema en cuestión es que el mismo operador de red celular establece unas restricciones de conexión a ese plan de datos las cuales solo permiten establecer conexión a terminales que accedan a internet por medio de la misma apn, por tanto esa apn trabajará casi como una vpn

Comment: Esas restricciones de conexión (un filtrado de tráfico por parte del ISP como te comenté anteriormente) pueden imposibilitarte hacer un PING pero existen otras alternativas como enviar un mensaje del tipo "heartbeat" (latido de corazón) a un servidor web (por poner un ejemplo) cada 10, 30 o 60 segundos y considerar caído el nodo si no se recibió un latido de corazón en un margen de tiempo definido (por norma general del doble o el triple del tiempo del intervalo entre latidos).